# WP8 Get application info

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, version

I'm developing an application that need information of my applications (not only this app). Specifically, I need the app name and version. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [`PackageManager.FindPackages()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br240969.aspx)  to get the list of applications and their information on WP8.

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    PackageManager packageManager = new PackageManager();

    IEnumerable<Windows.ApplicationModel.Package> packages = 
        (IEnumerable<Windows.ApplicationModel.Package>) packageManager.FindPackages();

    int packageCount = 0;
    foreach (var package in packages)
    {
        DisplayPackageInfo(package);

        packageCount += 1;
    }

    if (packageCount < 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No packages were found.");
    }
}

private static void DisplayPackageInfo(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package package)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", package.Id.Name);

    Console.WriteLine("FullName: {0}", package.Id.FullName);

    Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", package.Id.Version.Major, package.Id.Version.Minor,
        package.Id.Version.Build, package.Id.Version.Revision);

    Console.WriteLine("Publisher: {0}", package.Id.Publisher);

    Console.WriteLine("PublisherId: {0}", package.Id.PublisherId);

    Console.WriteLine("Installed Location: {0}", package.InstalledLocation.Path);

    Console.WriteLine("IsFramework: {0}", package.IsFramework);
}
```

Comment: I cannot find PackageManager class. Maybe it is not available for WP8

Comment: It comes under the namespace Windows.Management.Deployment

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest parsing WMAppManifest.xml
Code would be

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

string version = XDocument.Load("WMAppManifest.xml").Root.Element("App").Attribute("Version").Value;
// similarly for Title
```